# Shopify ScriptTag API and custom variables

Tags: shopify

I have a question regarding ScriptTag API - http://api.shopify.com/scripttag.html, is there a way to add couple variables if code is being added into the Thank You page? I would like to collect order_id and order_amount so client can track performance etc. but looking at the API it seems that I can only specify event and source or am I missing somthing?

cheers,
/Marcin

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can only specify event and source when creating a script tag.

However, since the structure of the Thank You page is known, you can grab the order number and total from the DOM using js.

Alternatively, You can couple your js tracking on the front end with data from the [Orders API](http://api.shopify.com/order.html) to get the data you need.